# Wi-Fi module 5 GHz

Tags: esp8266, wifi, wireless

What is a Wi-Fi module for an Arduino that works on 5 GHz? The ESP8266 - doesn't support 5 GHz according to:

- [Re: 802.11AC 5GHz](https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=42757#p187292)
- [Why can't ESP8266 operate in 5 GHz since 802.11N is supported](http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=4032)
- my own experiments.

Comment: You may need to drop "Arduino" from your search term and simply look for something supporting a UART or SPI interface and having an on-board protocol engine (since running a TCP stack on an Arduino is often problematic).  Unfortunately on-board TCP stacks, while initially seeming convenient, can turn out in the long run to have severe, unfixable problems frustrating serious use.

Answer (score 2):

I asked Microchip a while back if they planned to release a 5GHz WiFi module at any point in the near future. The answer was basically "No, there would be no benefit to it." For embedded systems there is no point in 5GHz since 2.4GHz is more than adequate and there are better long range solutions than WiFi (LoRa for instance).

Comment: I need to connect an Arduino to a 5Ghz Wifi hotspot. I will accept the first applicable workaround as an answer.

Comment: You may find an external module with SPI or UART interface. Arduino support for it may be lacking though. We can't do your shopping for you though.